# How to use cypher to create relationship between two nodes given their attributes in Neo4j

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I would like to do something like this

```
START n=node(*), m=node(*)  where has(n.userid) and has(m.userid) and n.userid='0' and m.userid='3'  create (n)-[FRIENDSHIP {status:2}]->(m) ;
```

However, Neo4j doesn't like the where clause. What is the best way to do this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What error did you get indicating that Neo4j didn't like the where clause?

I ran

```
START n=node(*), m=node(*)  
where has(n.name) and has(m.name) and n.name='Neo'
create (n)-[:FRIENDSHIP {status:2}]->(m)
```

on [console.neo4j.org](http://console.neo4j.org) and it ran fine. 
Note that you missed the : preceding the relation name. Was that the error it complained about?

What version are you using in case this still does not work?

Comment: Hi Luanne, thanks a lot for replying! I tried similarly START n=node(*), m=node(*) where has(n.userid) and has(m.userid) and n.userid='2' and n.userid='3' create (n)-[:FRIENDSHIP {status:2}]->(m) ; It doesn't report error. However, Neoclipse doesn't show the edge neither in the visualization.

Comment: I had the * in node(), it just lost after paste

Comment: This is Cypher 1.0. In 2.0 use a MATCH statement instead of START. This is due to a move towards a more declarative language structure, i.e. telling the machine what you want, instead of how you want it.